# MarkLogic - How to insert element into XML

Tags: xquery, marklogic, xpath-2.0

How to insert the node in XML.

```
let $a := <a><b>bbb</b></a>)
return
      xdmp:node-insert-after(doc("/example.xml")/a/b, <c>ccc</c>);
```

Expected Output:

```
<a><c>ccc</c><b>bbb</b></a>
```

Please help to get the output.

Answer (score 1):

You should be using `xdmp:node-insert-before` I believe in the following way:

```
xdmp:document-insert('/example.xml', <a><b>bbb</b></a>);

xdmp:node-insert-before(fn:doc('/example.xml')/a/b, <c>ccc</c>);

fn:doc('/example.xml');

(: returns <a><c>ccc</c><b>bbb</b></a> :)
```

Answer (score 1):

Nodes are immutable, so in-memory mutation can only be done by creating a new copy.

The copy can use the unmodified contained nodes from the original:

```
declare function local:insert-after(
    $prior as node(),
    $inserted as node()+
) as element()
{
    let $container := $prior/parent::element()
    return element {fn:node-name($container)} {
        $container/namespace::*,
        $container/attribute(),
        $prior/preceding-sibling::node(),
        $prior,
        $inserted,
        $prior/following-sibling::node()
    }
};

let $a := <a><b>bbb</b></a>
return local:insert-after($a//b, <c>ccc</c>)
```

Creating a copy in memory and then inserting the copy is faster than inserting and modifying a document in the database.

Depending on how many documents are inserted, the difference could be significant.

There are community libraries for copying with changes, but sometimes it's as easy to write a quick function (recursive where necessary).

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code to insert the element into the XML:

```
xdmp:node-insert-child(fn:doc('directory URI'),element {fn:QName('http://yournamesapce','elementName') }{$elementValue})
```

Here we use `fn:QName` to remove addition of `xmlns=""` in added node.